# Method to fit variable number of splines

Tags: clustering

If I have data that looks like below (independent observations), but the red and blue groups are unknown, is there a way to find the optimal number of curves (say, splines) to describe the data? In this case, the desired result would be to fit two lines, red and blue, and each observation would be assigned to it's respective curve.

[image: example data]

Comment: By "the red and blue groups are unknown", do you mean that *a priori*, you only have undifferentiated points, but you would like to *both* assign points to the two groups *and* fit splines? The differentiation will likely be hard for the points on the left.

Comment: @StephanKolassa, yes, that's correct. So, a spline based clustering method. And yeah, the points on the left will have higher misclassification.